# How to format code to '' || chr(10) || using plsql developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, formatting, plsqldeveloper

I need to convert a large amount of code into the below format:

```
'MERGE INTO employees emp' || chr(10) ||    
'USING (SELECT * FROM (SELECT (SELECT VALUE 
FROM departments 
WHERE CNTRY_CDE = ''100'' 
AND NAME = ''Scott'') BATCH_ID, SUBJECT_ID,' || chr(10) ||
```

as this code is being inserted in to a table as clob data.
Is there any way to do it?

The above given code is just the sample I have.

Comment: Just assign the value of your concatenated statement to your CLOB column. At runtime the `chr(10)` will be turned into a linefeed for you. Best of luck.

Comment: But i have normal SQl format code without ''||chr(10)|| . I need to add that formatting to the code.

Comment: Not really sure what problem you have with what you've shown. What are you converting into that format? You already have a static string with the whole command and you want to insert line feeds into it? If so how are you deciding where you want to put them? (Not sure why you'd do that anyway if it's code you'll extract and run later)

Comment: please see that i have large code in normal format: MERGE INTO employees emp USING (SELECT * FROM (SELECT (SELECT VALUE 
FROM departments WHERE CNTRY_CDE = '100' AND NAME = 'Scott') BATCH_ID, SUBJECT_ID like this. and i need to convert it to the above mentioned format. As the code is being inserted into clob and executed after extracting from it, it needs to be converted into that format. pl. help.

Comment: Why do you need to add line breaks to store it as a CLOB, or to extract it or run it? And you haven't said how you want to decide where to put the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have an SQL statement which looks something like

```
'MERGE INTO employees emp USING (SELECT * FROM (SELECT (SELECT VALUE FROM departments WHERE CNTRY_CDE = ''100'' AND NAME = ''Scott'') BATCH_ID, SUBJECT_ID,'
```

and you want it to look like

```
'MERGE INTO employees emp' || chr(10) || 'USING (SELECT * FROM (SELECT (SELECT VALUE FROM departments WHERE CNTRY_CDE = ''100'' AND NAME = ''Scott'') BATCH_ID, SUBJECT_ID,' || chr(10) ||
```

Despite my misgivings about the practicality of this, I suppose one way to accomplish it is something like the following:

```
declare 
  strOldstmt VARCHAR2(2000) := 'MERGE INTO employees emp USING (SELECT * FROM (SELECT (SELECT VALUE FROM departments WHERE CNTRY_CDE = ''100'' AND NAME = ''Scott'') BATCH_ID, SUBJECT_ID,';
  strNewstmt VARCHAR2(2000);
begin
  -- Test statements here

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strOldstmt=''' || strOldstmt || '''');

  strNewstmt := REPLACE(strOldstmt, 'USING', ''' || CHR(10) || '' USING') || ''' || CHR(10) || ';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strNewstmt=''' || strNewstmt || '''');
end;
```

The problem here is that this is very specific to this particular statement, which may not work with other statements; however, it does work for the example you've given and I'm not able to guess at what your more general requirements might be.

Best of luck.